# How do I calculate the number of times a word occurs in a sentence and prints out the indexes? (Python)

Tags: python, string, function

So I've been learning Python for some months now and was wondering how I would go about writing a program that will count the number of times a word occurs in a sentence and prints out the indexes.

Thank you.

Comment: Hey!, Welcome to SO. You have been using Python for months now but did you try to "Google" this before creating a question? Ppl here are not always willing to help if you didn't try something first (preferably with links)

Comment: I suggest you make an attempt at this, and when you hit a specific problem, come back and write a specific question about it.

Comment: Thank you, yes I did try to search on Google and found a Python program that calculates the number of times a word occurs in a sentence but it didn't print out the indexes.

Comment: This is not wonderland... please ask question.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Question and my answer changed. Here is the last suggestion:

```
string = "wordetcetcetcetcetcetcetcword"

import re
find = "word"
p = re.compile(find)
matches = [m.start() for m in p.finditer(string)]
print(matches)
```

Returns:

```
[0, 25]
```

Comment: While true, this provides generic advice that is available elsewhere (that people don't read). This has absolutely nothing to do with the question asked

Comment: @roganjosh I disagree. The original question was: Please provide a step to step guide on how to solve this.

Comment: You edited in some code for an answer. I voted to close. Comment for clarification  or downvote and move on. Do you think that "Google this" is helpful for posterity when you use this site for work?

Comment: @roganjosh Yep, the question and my answer changed. let's move on! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
def count_index(string, search_term):
    return (search_term,
        string.count(search_term),
        [string.replace(search_term, '', i).index(search_term) + (len(search_term)*i) for i in range(string.count(search_term))]
    )
```

Returns

```
>>> a = test.count_index("python is a very good language, i like python because python is good", "python")
>>> a
('python', 3, [0, 39, 54])
```

The logic is (albeit a bit bodgy) basically going over a range of the occurences of the `search_term` on the given `string` and thus indexes the word, adds the index to the list; then it replaces the word with nothing and then for the next term it adds on the amount of characters removed according to the current index and the loop works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

We welcome learners, too. The following might get you going; which includes **basic** treatment of punctuation, as well as returning case-variations at the corresponding index:

```
import string
#
mask = str.maketrans('', '', string.punctuation) # Punctuation mask.
#
def aFunc(sentence, word):
   words = sentence.translate(mask).split(' ') # Remove punctuation.
   indices = [(e,w) for (e,w) in enumerate(words) if w.lower() == word.lower()] # Collect (index,word) pairs.  
   return (len(indices), indices)
```

---

```
s = 'The cat fell out of the hat. Then thE cAt fell asleep against the haT=:)'

aFunc(s, 'HAT')
(2, [(6, 'hat'), (14, 'haT')])

aFunc(s, 'the')
(4, [(0, 'The'), (5, 'the'), (8, 'thE'), (13, 'the')])

aFunc(s, 'Cat')
(2, [(1, 'cat'), (9, 'cAt')])
```

Answer (score -1):

There are several ways to do that, but here is one trivial solution that counts the number of instances of a word, but do not take e.g. punctation into account:

```
from collections import Counter
s = "This is true. This is false."
c = Counter(s.split(' '))
print(c['This'])  # Prints "2"
```